# discord.js TypeError: fn is not a function

Tags: discord.js

I'm trying to make an array with the IDs of channels found with the names of channels from another array, but it returns the error "TypeError: fn is not a function". This is the relevant code.

```
    var filtered_channel_ids = [];
    filtered_channel_names.forEach(element => filtered_channel_ids.push(client.channels.cache.find(element).id))
    console.log(filtered_channel_ids);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Collection.prototype.find()` requires a function. For example:

```js
collection.find((element) => element.name === 'Hello World')
```

However, `element` is a string (or so I assume, you haven't shown the `filtered_channel_names` array). It looks like you want to find a channel by it's name, for which you can use something similar to the function above.

```js
client.channels.cache.find((c) => c.name === element).id
```

---

In addition, there are several optimizations you can make to your code. First of all, you can use `Array.prototype.reduce()` instead of `forEach()`.

Also, since channels are mapped by their ID, you can use `findKey()` instead of `find()` to automatically return the channel id.

```js
// original
var filtered_channel_ids = [];
filtered_channel_names.forEach(element => filtered_channel_ids.push(client.channels.cache.find(element).id))
console.log(filtered_channel_ids);

// new and improved
var filtered_channel_ids = filtered_channel_ids.reduce((acc, name) => 
  acc.push(client.channels.cache.findKey((c) => c.name === name), [])
console.log(filtered_channels_ids)
```

Comment: Lol I accidentally marked this as community wiki. My bad.